# Post Base64 converted image to Node.js Backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, base64

I have converted a image to base64  that are in my react.js application register form. It covert this image and send it to Node.js server with MySQL database. In here `axios` post request is not is unsuccessful because converted url is very large.

frontend console shows net::ERR_FAILED 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large). Is there any way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs, by default, has a smaller limit for request body, which is what you seem to be running into. The limit can be increased using code snippet below in nodejs while initializing the body parser package

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '10mb'}));
```

You can read more on the defaults and other settings [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#limit-3)

---

If you are using querystring to send the data to Node, try updating the code to send it as an HTTP POST with appropriate request body

Comment: i tried that one also still shows that error  the error is                      xhr.js:251 
        
        
        GET http://localhost:5000/api/verifyuserEmail?user_type=Passenger&fname=Hemantha&lname=Wanniarachchi&email=hnwanniarachchi98%40gmail.com&contactno=0000000000&address=ggg&password=Hemantha%40&ID=data:image%2Fpng%3Bbase64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZ0AAAITCAYAAADcjcGXAAAABGdBTUEAALGeYUxB9wAAACBjSFJNAACHEAAAj3b7%2B%2F8c94%2F8BsXHFegRjEeUAAAAASUVORK5CYII%3D net::ERR_FAILED 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Comment: How big is the image? Is it more than 10MB in size? If so, update the limit to 20 or 50

Comment: No. It's like 200kB.

Comment: Are you using querystring to send the data to the server? If so, try changing that to use HTTP POST method with JSON data in request body. Nodejs limits the total size of HTTP headers (query string, cookies) in a request to 8KB

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the image data as base64, you can upload the image file directly to the server if you don't want resize it.

Comment: No i don't want resize i want to save it in mysql database in my project